# Date according to culture [english and arabic]

Tags: asp.net, .net, datetime, internationalization, sitefinity

I have a date binded in a asp.net repeater control

```
<%# Eval("PublishedDate") %>
```

I have two cultures: English and Arabic.

currently I am getting this `[29/04/35 07:00:00 م]` date in arabic but i want following `[5 يناير 2014]` format

and in english I am getting `[3/1/2014 7:00:00 PM]` but i want following format `[January 5, 2014]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resources by creating 2 local resource files one for English {PageName}.en.resx and the other for Arabic {PageName}.ar.resx and put the format in.

Steps:

- Create 2 local resources for the page, for example **Default.aspx.en.resx** and **Default.aspx.ar.resx**
- Add DateFormat item in each resource, in Arabic resource file
  **DateFormat  ==> d MMM yyyy** and in English resource file **DateFormat ==> MMM d,yyyy**
- Change the binding expression in ASPX to be like this `<%# Eval("PublishedDate", etLocalResourceObject("DateFormat").ToString()) %>`
- last thing is to change Culture of the page to tell ASP.NET engine
  which local resource use

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [System.Globalization.CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?ppud=4) and the associated format classes?